# Ehcache cache the data with support cluster disk storage (replication)

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory, ehcache-2

I am using Ehcache technologies in our application and it is working in single server data persist in disk, if we moving to production, we have two different server which is clustered in our application.

if first request comes to **server A**, it will cache respect **server A** OS disk level cached data and working fine, similarly, if request goes to **server B**, the application can not find the cached data because the the cached disk object in **server A disk**. how to we replicate both disk in our **ehcache-config.xml**?

Comment: dear all, how do we maintain the cache data if server restart, the data should not loss. please suggest the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into clustering support with Terracotta.
See the documentation for this:

- [Ehcache 3.x line](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/clustered-cache.html)
- [Ehcache 2.x line](http://www.terracotta.org/open-source/)

Comment: hi, thanks and if I am restart the my server, the cache data is gone. how are we stored it permanently. please advise.